# Probar una funcion asincronica con jasmine sin usar setTimeout

Tags: angularjs, promesas, jasmine

Me gustaria si alguien me puede ayudar a testear esta funcion sin usar el setTimeout que estoy usando en el ARCHIVO DE TEST. despues de investigar mucho pude hacerlo andar, pero ese setTimeout es una bomba de tiempo.
probe con jasmine-promises y de mil maneras diferentes pero ninguna me funciono

**service:**

```
angular.module('moduloPrueba', [])
  .factory('asincronico', function($q) {

  return {
    tes:tes,
  };


  function tes(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    setTimeout(function () {

      deferred.resolve(79);
    }, 50);

    // Return the deferred promise
    return deferred.promise;
  }

});
```

**jasmine test:**

```
describe('description', function () {
  var asi;
  var root;
  var res;

  beforeEach(function () {
    module('moduloPrueba');
    inject(function (asincronico, $rootScope) {
      root = $rootScope;
      asi = asincronico;
    })
  });

  it('should ', function (done) {
    asi.tes().then(function (resp) {
      res = resp;
      done();
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
      root.$digest();
      expect(res).toEqual(79);
      expect(res).not.toEqual(123);
    }, 200);

  });

});
```

Comment: Que quieres testiar en realidad? Porque el codigo que tienes usa un timeout

Comment: ¿Has probado a utilizar **$httpBackend**? Quizás te pueda ayudar este tutorial [$httpBackend](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/06/26/unit-testing-http-ngmock-fundamentals/)

Comment: @Klaimmore quiero probar lo mismo pero si usar el timeout que llama al $digest y a los expects en el test. supongo que hay alguna manera de que pueda funcionar sin ello

Comment: que version de jasmine utilizas?

Comment: @Klaimmore     "jasmine-core": "^3.1.0",

Answer (score 0):

Segun la [documentacion para it()](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.0/global.html#it)

Si quieres probar una funcion como esta:

```
function tes(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    setTimeout(function () {

      deferred.resolve(79);
    }, 50);

    // Return the deferred promise
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Entonces deberias escribir el test como:

```
it('should resolve 79 after 50ms', function (done) {
    asi.tes().then(function (resp) {
      expect(resp).toEqual(79);
      done();
    });
}, 51);
```

El resultado de la promesa `resp` lo pruebas en el success callback y el tiempo que deberia demorar la promesa, lo especificas como ultimo argumento en `it`

Comment: hoy llego a mi casa y pruebo.